# Upload multiple file from different inputs

Tags: php, codeigniter, file

I want to upload 3 different file from 3 different inputs, I can upload one but I don't know how to upload 3 using different input files in 3 inputs at the same time. I've spent hours but I still can't get it. Any help would be cool.

PS: Messed up controller.

My view code

```
 <hr class="hrlog3">
 div class="form-group">
 label class="addplabell">II. WARM UP EXCERCISE
 <input type="file" class="form-control2" name="file"></label>
 </div> 

 <hr class="hrlog3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="addplabell">III. DRILL 1
 <input type="file" class="form-control2" name="file2"></label>
 </div> 

 <hr class="hrlog3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="addplabell">IV. DRILL 2
 <input type="file" class="form-control2" name="file3"></label>
  </div>
```

My controller

```
$config = array(
'upload_path' => 'upload/',
'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf',
'max_size' =>1024,
'file_name' => url_title($this->input->post('file')),
'file_name2' => url_title($this->input->post('file2')),
'file_name3' => url_title($this->input->post('file3'))
);

$this->load->library('upload',$config);
$this->db->insert('sessions',array(
'file_name' => $this->upload->file_name,
'file_name2' => $this->upload->file_name,
'file_name3' => $this->upload->file_name        
));
```

Comment: I don't think you need the url_title. I also think there are plenty of other stack overlfow examples.

Comment: Something like that maybe? `'file_name' => $this->upload->file_name,
'file_name2' => $this->upload->file_name2,
'file_name3' => $this->upload->file_name3`

Comment: try to upload the file 1 by 1, $config should have 1 file only